# donation counter on starting page

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

I need a donation counter (total sum), which shows on the starting page and on a specific page. My problem here is, that I included a snippet to get the total donation and these donations come from one specific product. I managed to get to get the total sum of donations and I can display it on the product page. But I want to display it on the startpage and on a specific page. I wrote a **product-sold-count.liquid** as following:

```
{% assign productStartCount = product.metafields.stock.initial | times:1 %}
{% if productStartCount > 0 %}
{% assign productInventory = product.variants.first.inventory_quantity %}
{% assign totalSum = productStartCount | minus:productInventory | times: product.price | times: product.metafields.donation.percent | divided_by: 10000 %}
<p>{{ totalSum }} € were donated until now!</p>
{% endif %}
```

Now I want to get this `totalSum` to another page or more likely to the start page and to other pages? I tried: `{% include 'product-sold-count' %}` on the specific liquids like **page.liquid** or **theme.liquid** but that won't work. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on product page, you have the variable `product`. But on other pages, this variable is longer valid.

In order to have total count for all product, you can repeat the above code for each product and get the sum of all products. Note that Shopify provide `all_products` variable, but limit to 20 products per page. You can use `collection.products` if it's on a collection (or, assign all donation products to donation collection then get all products of this collection)

```
{% assign allProductCount = 0 %}

{% for product in  all_products %}
  {% assign productStartCount = product.metafields.stock.initial | times:1 %}
  {% if productStartCount > 0 %}
    {% assign productInventory = product.variants.first.inventory_quantity %}
    {% assign totalSum = productStartCount | minus:productInventory | times: 
  product.price | times: product.metafields.donation.percent | divided_by: 10000 %}

    {% assign allProductCount = allProductCount | plus: totalSum %}
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}

<p>{{ allProductCount }} € were donated until now!</p>
```